# write unicode string to csv in c#

Tags: c#, csv, unicode-string

I used following code to create csv file from unicode string:

```
context.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
context.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Utf8;        
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fundName + ".csv");
context.Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble());                

String output ="";        
output += "Name, callNumber" + "\n";
String output ="علی,34343555" + "\n";     
context.Response.Write(output);
```

The problem is unicode character that don't show correctly "علی".

Thanks for any guides.
Regards
Ali

Comment: What are you reading the file with?

Comment: Did you confirm that UTF8 is a suitable encoding for arabic characters?

Comment: @Oded - thanks.  I had similar problems with reading accented characters and found UTF7 worked but UTF8 did not.

Comment: @ScruffyDuck Nonsense. UTF8 is a complete Unicode encoding.

Comment: So far as I know, almost all apps that read CSV, read ASCII/ANSI. Unless you are going to process this file yourself, you may be out of luck.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan  Shows how little I know about it then 8-)

Comment: have a look at this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5f5x7kt.aspx it talks about BOM and encoding that sounds like this could be the issue that you are running into

Comment: Can you show where you are using UTF8Encoding and replace it with  new UTF8Encoding(false)

Comment: here is something that you can try It may sound weird but using the Tab should get this to work.. so replace the lines where you have 
`output += "Name, callNumber" + "\n";`
`String output ="علی,34343555" + "\n";`  with 
`output += "Name, callNumber" + "\t";`
`String output ="علی,34343555" + "\t";`

Comment: also this line String output ="";        
output += "Name, callNumber" + "\n";
String output ="علی,34343555" + "\n";  should not work because you already have output declared.. you need this don't you 
String output ="";        
`output += "Name, callNumber" + "\t";
output +="علی,34343555" + "\t";`

Comment: Can you read the output correctly with a unicode text editor (e.g. Notepad++)?

Answer (score 6):

I would rather use streamwriter to write unicode characters using UTF-8 Encoding.
Snippet:

```
 using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(new FileStream("c:/Temp.csv", FileMode.Create), Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                    sw.WriteLine(string.Join(",", s));
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! It works great. Care to elaborate on what exactly the string.join does here? Without the string.join you end up with single lines but with the string.join it ends up as a properly comma separated line.

Comment: String.join just appends comma before the string. The trick here is Encoding.UTF8 option.

Answer (score 2):

A few problems with the code.

- `context.Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble());` writes the BOM for UTF-32 **not** UTF-8.
- the output variable is defined twice.

I suggest trying this:

```
context.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
context.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Utf8;        
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fundName + ".csv");

String output ="";        
output += "Name, callNumber" + "\n";
output +="علی,34343555" + "\n";     
context.Response.Write(output);
context.Response.End()
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `Encoding.Unicode` for writing Unicode CSV file:

```
File.WriteAllText("path/to/file.csv", yourString, Encoding.Unicode);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Response.Clear();
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "Application/vnd.ms-excel");
Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=filename1.csv");
var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("your content with chinese characters");
var result = Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble().Concat(data).ToArray();
var str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result);
Response.Write(str);
Response.Flush();
Response.SuppressContent = true;
```

Comment: To display Chinese characters in the CSV file, you need to use the encoding UTF-8-BOM. Above code is doing that.